# How can I know the DPI of a PNG image file?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, dpi

I'm working with PNG images in WPF, and they are not rendering at the size I expect. I suspect the problem has something to do with the DPI setting of the image files. However, I don't know how to check the DPI setting of an image file. Is there a way to view an image file's DPI in Visual Studio?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.dpiy(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Clemens, Does that work for PNG files on your system? I wrote some code to query the property Hans Passant referenced, and I have thereby learned that one of my PNG files has a DPI of 149.986999511719. However, no DPI is listed on the Details tab of the file properties. I've looked at several PNG files now, and I have not seen DPI listed for any of them.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at a JPG file. Seems that DPI is listed in the Details of a PNG.